# Is it possible to download ONLY files changed in a commit/revision using git archive

Tags: git, bitbucket

Using git archive commmand is it possible to download only the changed/affected files from a repository for a particular commit id ? Is it possible using the web interface @ bitbucket ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  `git archive` is to create an archive file, like tar.

Answer (score 11):

List the files changed in a commit with `git diff-tree` and pass them to the command line of `git archive`.

```
git archive --format=zip --output=commit_files.zip <tree-ish> `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <tree-ish> | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`
```

Comment: Didn't expect this to work, but it worked like a charm! +1. Just replace `<tree-ish>` with commit e.g. `e8d7a3d`

Comment: I did so but got `sed: 1: ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g": unused label 'a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an archive file focused on a specific commit, but it archives the entire repo, not just the changed/affected files. You could probably figure those out by the log though.

Example: if you wanted the latest changes from bitbucket it would look something like:

```
git archive -format=tar --remote=<PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO> HEAD
```

Comment: "You could probably figure those out by the log though" and is there a command which automatically tars up only the changed files ?

Comment: No, you can run this command `git show <commit>` to see the patch of what was changed, but you're not getting the whole file. If you wanted the file, you'd have to do some crazy scripting where you piped the output of the show or log command, parsed out the file names, grabbed each of those files and put them in an archive...Not exactly easy.