# How to download .zip from GitHub for a particular commit sha?

Tags: git, github

I want to download a .zip with the source of a library hosted on github, but I don't want the master, because every time I download I could be downloading a different version.

This particular library does not have tags, so I can't use that.

So how do I download the source.zip for a specific commit sha?

Comment: This doesn't need to be tagged with php or composer-php, does it?

Comment: I assume this doesn't work for DevOps

Answer (score 278):

You can put the sha that you want in the download url:

`https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}/archive/{sha}.zip`

As a general rule, if you have a url that works, you can replace "master" with the specific sha you want.

On unix:

`wget https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}/archive/{sha}.zip`

Keep in mind that if this is a private repo then wget will not work unless you pass an OAuth token as well.

Here's more info on that:

[Having trouble downloading Git archive tarballs from Private Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046027/having-trouble-downloading-git-archive-tarballs-from-private-repo)

Comment: Wasn't expecting that (cool) way of doing it. Was expecting git commands ;)

Comment: Check this link as well - Might be looking for this  instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503019/341117

Comment: You can use the short sha too!

Comment: Even if I use `wget -O` to rename the archive ZIP file, when unzipped I get a big ugly SHA1 directory name. Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 46):

When viewing the commit's code, click the button "Browse Code" on the upper right, after that click on "Download ZIP".

Comment: They have a 'Clone or Download' button now, where you can 'Download ZIP'.

Comment: "Clone or Download" is the new button that replaces the old "Clone" and "Download" buttons. The new-button doesn't do specific versions - use the way Zeki described

Comment: This worked for me in Feb 2017. It did download the repo with changes at the timestamp of the selected commit.

Comment: In 2023, this still works, but the button is now called "Code". From a branch, "Code" opens a drop-down that includes that "Download ZIP" link. For a specific commit, click on that commit, then click on "Browse Files" in the upper right corner, and then "Code" appears and provides a ZIP link pointing to the zip file for the commit.

Answer (score 9):

This is a an old question, but wanted to mention that if you want just the commit as a patch, and not the whole repo at the time of the commit, you can use:

```
$ wget http://github.com/username/repo/commit/sha1.patch
#                        ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^        ^^^^
#                        change   change      change
```

The `/commit` and `.patch` parts being the important part.

This is particularly useful if you want to merge in a change that was reversed a while back and therefore doesn't exist in the forked repo.

Answer (score 4):

For those who came here looking for a way to **download a particular file (or directory)**, from a particular commit (or branch):

```
git_user="user-name"
git_project="project-name"
commit_or_branch="sha-id or branch name"
dir_or_file="path/to/dir-or-file"

archive_url="https://github.com/${git_user}/${git_project}/archive/${commit_or_branch}.tar.gz"

wget -O - ${archive_url} | tar xz --strip=1 "${git_project}-${commit_or_branch}/${dir_or_file}"
```

The advantage of downloading the archive as `tar.gz`, is that you can directly pipe *wget* into *tar* command, so it will **extract the gz on the fly**.

Comment: wasteful. files can be downloaded directly, subdirectories can be downloaded via github's SVN interface, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo

Comment: @MilaNautikus your link for using `svn` - **requires SVN** to be installed first, while `wget` is already available on most platforms. Instead of downvoting, post a useful answer.